# Load low resolution images using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

As the title suggests, is there a way to load a low resolution image (maybe about half the image's original size) using Glide? I don't know if it makes sense but I basically need it so data users of my application can minimize their data consumption. I need it to be the final image that Glide loads into the view (not thumbnail).

Comment: You need to store low resolution images in your server to do that.

Comment: is it the only possible way? i have 1000+ images the workload of editing them one by one, uploading them, and taking their urls is a bit too much

Comment: How would Glide load a low resolution image from the server if it isn't on the server? To scale the image down Glide would first need to load it. And then no data is saved. It needs to be a server side solution. You could search for "batch resize images" and maybe find some tool to partly automate the process.

Comment: How about preloading the images into cache with custom width and height?

Answer (score 2):

I Suggest Server will do this 
and you can also compress and resize the image when load

```
RequestOptions reqOptions = new RequestOptions()
    .fitCenter() 
    .override(100, 100);

 Glide.with(context)
     .asBitmap()
     .apply(reqOptions)
     .load(imageUrl)
     .into(bitmapView);
```